# Spark - creating a DataFrame from JSON - only the first row is processed

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a DataFrame with JSON strings from a text file. First I merge JValues:

```
  def mergeSales(salesArray: JArray, metrics: JValue): List[String] = {
    salesArray.children
      .map(sale => sale merge metrics)
      .map(merged => compact(render(merged)))
  }
```

Then I write the strings to a file:

```
out.write(mergedSales.flatMap(s => s getBytes "UTF-8").toArray)
```

Data in the resulting file looks like this and there are no commas between the objects and no new lines:

```
{"store":"New Sore_1","store_id":"10","store_metric":"1234567"}{"store":"New Sore_1","store_id":"10","store_metric":"98765"}
```

The problem is when I'm creating a DataFrame it contains only the first row (with store_metric 1234567), ignoring the second one.

What is my mistake in creating a DataFrame? And what should I do for the data to be parsed correctly?
Here is how I'm trying to create a DataFrame:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("data.txt").values)
```

Comment: Since the data is not nested, can you split on the `}` character and write the file back out? if there isn't an easier option of course!

Comment: or change your `mergeSales` function to insert a new line after the doc. Also, are you aware that spark.read.json is expecting each json doc on a new line?